# PropertyChanged event not changing UI for binding using converter

Tags: wpf

I have below xaml for "canvas"...i want to change its **visibility** depends on property change.

XAML:

```
<d1:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis" />

Visibility="{Binding Path=IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

I have this Visibility property in ViewModel

```
private bool _isVisible;
    public bool IsVisible
    {
        get { return _isVisible; }
        set
        {
            _isVisible = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsVisible");
        }
    }
```

This is my Converter code:

```
class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public BooleanToVisibilityConverter() { }
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public bool Collapse { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region IValueConverter Members
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool bValue = (bool)value;
        if (bValue)
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
            //if (Collapse)
            //    return Visibility.Collapsed;
            //else
            //    return Visibility.Hidden;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //Visibility visibility = (Visibility)value;

        //if (visibility == Visibility.Visible)
        //    return true;
        //else
        //    return false;
        return value;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

While debugging I observed my Setter is changing the property value but its not hitting break point on my converter. Converter is getting hit only initially while loading window. After that it doesnt get triggered even though property is changed.

Comment: Is the property changed correctly? That is, is it set through the property and not directly against the field? You've not shown us that code.

Comment: I am using Prism Propert changed event,

    namespace Microsoft.Practices.Prism.ViewModel
{
    [Serializable]
    public abstract class NotificationObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        protected NotificationObject();

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpression);
        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(params string[] propertyNames);
        protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName);
    }

Comment: thanks, but that's not what I asked. I asked how you're updating the IsVisible property (are you accidentally setting the field instead of the property?)

Comment: I m doing it for one of the event aggregator method                if(carStatus = "Reserved")
 this.IsVisible = true;
else
 this.IsVisible = false;

Answer (score 0):

I read that you are using Prism so try to change your RaisePropertyChanged in this form:

```
RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsVisible);
```

Comment: does that has to do anything with my view models. the above code is for child view model B..which acts as observable collection for parent view model A. Initially i am setting properties from A by calling new instance of B.

Comment: So, I think that there aren't errors in the part of code that you post. There is sure something wrong in the other part but without the code it's not easy to help you. Maybe you have a binding error, but wotout the code is not possible to find it. Did you see if there  is an advice in the output window?